# Sendgrid Template: How to change text color dynamically?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

with Sendgrid dynamic template, I'm trying to figure out how to use dynamic data for style property so I can change text color depending on some dynamic data.

in the following example, I'm trying to use dynamic data `colorHash` such as `#ddd` for style color property. but it doesn't seem to work. so I'd appreciate it if anyone knows how to dynamically change text color in a smart way.

```
<p style="color: {{ colorHash }}">Ciao {{{ username }}}</p>
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? If you inspect the HTML email, do you see the correct output colour?

Answer (score 2):

Contacted the sendgrid support team, they told me how to achieve what I want to do.

pass css in string as dynamic data, not just color hash you wanna use, so you can insert it into style property in a dynamic template html.

```
dynamic_data: {
   yourCSS: `color: ${yourDynamicColor};`
}

in template html,
<span style={{ yourCSS }}>Dynamic Color Text</span>
```